# How do I solve Ax=y using this decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following expression:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & -2 & -0.5 \\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\ -3 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For which I have found $p_1 = 0$, $p_2 = 2$, $p_3 = -2$. The columns of the above matrix are the eigenvectors $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$ of this matrix $A$:
$$ A =
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 & 0 \\
-2 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & -2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By expressing $y = p_1e_1 + p_2e_2 + p_3e_3 $ and $x = q_1e_1 + q_2e_2 + q_3e_3 $, I want to solve the equation $Ax = y$.

I have tried a brute force approach by simply constructing $x$ as a vector formed from the 3 eigenvectors, since I know the values. But this result in a very complicated algebra which involves 3 variables at each term in the matrix on the left hand side, which cannot be discernably solved using a cleaner linear algebra method. How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried using coordinate vectors with respect to the two basis and the diagonal representation of $A $ (wrt to the eigenvector basis).

Comment: Are coordinate vectors the same thing as eigenvectors?

Comment: No, coordinate vector of $x$ wrt to basis $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ would be $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ where $u'i's $ satisfy $x=u_1b_1+u_2b_2+u_3b_3$

Answer (score 2):

Let $[A]=D$ be the representation of $A $ wrt to the basis of eigenvectors. This is diagonal. The coordinate vectors of $x,y$, with respect to the same basis, are $(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ and $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ respectively. 
So you can use these:
 [D(q_1,q_2,q_3)=(p_1,p_2,p_3).]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what AnyAD is alluding to:

If $ X $ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $ A $, then $ X^{-1} A X = D $ where $ D $ is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Now, if you want to solve $ A x = y $ you can instead solve $ X^{-1} A X X^{-1} x = X^{-1} y $ or, equivalently, $ D X^{-1} x = X^{-1} y $.

Now, you are saying that $ x = X q $ and $ y = X p $.  So, $ q = X^{-1} x $ and $ p = X^{-1} y $.  So, we find that $ D q = p $.

Anyway, you may be able to now piece it all together.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the answer. This is such a surprising find. I tried solving it and I got $q_1 = 6$ $q_2 = -3$ $q_3 = 0$. Why does it happen to be equal to $y$? Is this a coincidence or is there a deeper relationship?

Comment: I am not a details person, so I haven't worked through the problem to that degree.